# Blender game engine seeing through gun

Tags: game-engine

I've looked at the other questions similar to mine but they all talk about the normals. After displaying the normals, it seems my normals are fine - yet my object still can be seen through.
[image: gun]

[image: gun3dnormals]

[image: gunnormalsside]

Here is the blend file:
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36891

Comment: You have connected a lot of vertices with some vertices where I guess you shouldn't. If you grab the plane(from the side of the camera) that seems transparent towards the y -axis you are gonna see at least 3 of them. Also did you tweak any normals somehow manualy? I see an edge normal that appears strange. Plus you have 10 double vertices. If you clean the above I think it will be fixed. I would just delete that box and remake it. That blue-ish color is death for the eyes btw.

Answer (score 1):

**Normals are pointing inwards**

Solution: flip them.

But: They do look right at your picture.

**Transparency enabled**.

Solution: disable transparency in the material tab. As your model does not need any transparency this should be no issue.

**Mirrored the object**. That makes the normals point towards the opposite direction (see the first option). This can happen on negative scale on one or three axis (scale by -1). It is possible you have an according modifier mirroring your mesh.

Solution: Mirror again, scale back, flip normals and/or review your modifiers.

Comment: I checked your file. It is: Transparency enabled.